# Regular Expression issue with unicode characters

Tags: java, regex

I have following reqular expression it suppose to accept following inputs

```
yes
no
b 03211111111 10
```

Pattern:

```
Pattern.compile(
    "^((B\\s(92|0)?(3[0-9]{2,9})\\s([1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|200))|(y)|(yes)|(n)|(no))$",
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE
);
```

but today i found that it accept one input like following

```
b 03211111111 10?
```

in above line that question mark is in opposite direction and i dont know how i can type here.

it look like some unicode character, i just want to restrict my regular expression to just get input like

```
b 03211111111 10
```

Following is code

```
balShareReq =   Pattern.compile("^((B\\s(92|0)?(3[0-9]{2,9})\\s([1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|200))|(y)|(yes)|(n)|(no))$",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher   =   balShareReq.matcher(vo.getMessage());             
            if( matcher.find() ) {
//my business logic 
}
```

Regards,
imran

Comment: You mean that you have `¿` in your input? Or `⸮`? It doesn't look like your pattern should accept either of them...

Comment: Are there simple rules that determine what should be accepted? Those examples are pretty broad.

Answer (score 1):

You have some other error in your program:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
"^((B\\s(92|0)?(3[0-9]{2,9})\\s([1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|200))|(y)|(yes)|(n)|(no))$",
Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE
);

p.matcher("b 03211111111 10?").matches();  // false
p.matcher("b 03211111111 10¿").matches();  // false
p.matcher("b 03211111111 10⸮").matches();  // false
```

**Update**

You're using [`find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) where you should probably be using [`matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29). From the java doc, `matches`:

> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.

While `find`:

> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.

But even `find` should not match with your given pattern, unless the `¿` is on a line after the main pattern (since you have `$` at the end of your pattern).

Comment: in following two scenarios it returns true to me p.matcher("b 03211111111 10¿").matches();
p.matcher("b 03211111111 10⸮").matches();

Comment: `o__o` Update your question with more code so we can see the context. This should not return true. Might you be using an outdated java version? Anything else you think might be relevant?

Comment: it look like i have to use matcher.matches() rather then matcher.find(). please comment

Answer (score 0):

Your regex fails because of your $ at the end.
The $ means the regex must pass until the end of the string is reached.
Remove the $ or allow some other chars before the end of the string.

-> "...|(y)|(yes)|(n)|(no))¿?$" would pass the ¿ char (? means optional in regex)

-> "...|(y)|(yes)|(n)|(no))" would pass all chars at the end

Comment: OP says that `"b 03211111111 10⸮"` matches when it shouldn't, not that it should match.